# Teachings of Shakuni

Tags: mahabharata, duryodhana, shakuni

In some translation of Mahabharat, I read a conversation between Duryodhana and Shakuni, but I can't find it today on Google.  It goes something like this:

Duryodhana asks Shakuni some question.

In response, Shakuni answers the question with a question.

He says, "Do you know why God created the mind and the mouth as two separate?  So that the mind can think one thing and the mouth can speak another (entirely different thing)."

Do you know the quote, or where I can find the conversation?

Comment: That seems like a weird thing for anyone in Hinduism to say. "God created" isn't used, because it is completely undescriptive and things like this are also due to karma, so putting all the creation onto God is wrong.

Comment: This conversation you quote is sourced from the Star Plus Mahabharata. And definitely they're not "teachings" but his personal views.